# Mule - java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map

Tags: rest, mule, classcastexception, http-request

I want to write a mule application which will read the database for unprocessed records, club them in JSON payload format and then hit a REST webservice. 
I am able to read the records from the database and able to convert the database records in JSON. However, whenever I run the application I am getting following exception

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map

Here is my Mule configuration XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:db="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db" xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db/current/mule-db.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd">
    <db:mysql-config name="MySQL_Configuration" host="localhost" port="3306" user="root" database="my_database_name" doc:name="MySQL Configuration"/>
    <http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" protocol="HTTPS" host="example.net" port="8000" basePath="API" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration"/>
    <flow name="cwg_clientFlow">
        <poll doc:name="Poll">
            <db:select config-ref="MySQL_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
                <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[SELECT * FROM cwg_ws_data WHERE SyncFlag = 0]]></db:parameterized-query>
            </db:select>
        </poll>
        <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <json:object-to-json-transformer   doc:name="Object to JSON" />
        <logger message="JSON Payload is #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/cwg" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP">
            <http:request-builder>
                <http:query-params expression="#[payload]"/>
                <http:header headerName="access_token" value="MQTgpMUmyQLt134maB6vPp6oWFgMtGsqzIlpCN74"/>
            </http:request-builder>
        </http:request>
        <logger message="webservice response #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

I am unable to understand where it is going wrong

Please help me, I am trying this since last 2 days.

Thanks in advance

-Paresh (kendreparesh@gmail.com)

Comment: It seems like you are using the payload as query parameters for the HTTP request, but in order to set them as an expression they need to be a Map (query key/query value). That's what the casting error is about. What do you actually need as query parameters?

Comment: The webservice is expecting the payload in JSON format, since I am converting database rows in JSON format and trying to pass this JSON to webservice.

Comment: Then you don't need the query params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing this line.

```
<http:query-params expression="#[payload]"/>
```

It should work. As your payload is Json String and you are trying to map it to Query params which expects Map. Also for POST your payload will converted to body.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked for me:) However I am getting "Response code 401 mapped as failure" as a exception, but I can take it from there. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

expression in query-params must be a map. If you are going to pass data as query-params, why are you doing object to json? Try removing below two lines -

```
<json:object-to-json-transformer   doc:name="Object to JSON" />
        <logger message="JSON Payload is #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

Comment: The REST weebservice is expecting the payload in JSON format since I am converting the records from the database in JSON.

Comment: Ok, in that case you should remove query params, like @anupambhusari said.